# Logging in Java application where none exist originally

Tags: java, swing, aop, log4j2

I am having a fairly large legacy (swing) application and currently brainstorming and evaluating the strategies to  add logging in it.

**Key point is that it's fairly large (like I said above) and thinking what could be the strategy to do it quickly and completely (100% coverage for argument sake) (let's say logging is no customer facing core business functionality, so let's say not getting paid for it)**

So the two strategies as such are -

- Do use log4j2 add the debug statements, add appenders, file rolling rules, add dynamic on/off and change of log levels etc and thus do it the way it ideally should be done.
- Use AOP to define endpoints and advices declaratively/programmaticly. Device such elaborate rules, add in the rest of the part (appenders, rolling rules etc.) and thus wont be touching each and every file and adding a revision just for that.

The second strategy is what I want to explore if someone has experience with, if somebody has gone that route.

The cons I can think of -

- No standard / convention in apps, would be 99% impossible to define endpoints completely
- Sphagetti and unmaintainable code in AOP module above, largely a result of the above problem
- Adding same and matching set to logging to future classes.

Can you guys suggest me wither ways

Comment: That should depend on what you want to log. If there is no discernable pattern in where the debug statements would be, and you do not want to log everything (like, "method XXX called with parameters ...") than AOP is obviously not the way.

Comment: You could also do some string replacement magic with your IDE. E.g. insert a log statement in every actionPerformed() method.

Answer (score 1):

While I am a big proponent of refactoring and clean code, I suggest you use AspectJ to add logging and see how far you get. Probably you will be surprised by how much logging you get with a little aspect.

IMHO logging is a cross-cutting concern and not core functionality. I would try to avoid logging in my core code. My expecience with AspectJ is only positive, I warmly recommend it. You should take some time to get acquainted with its power, though.

If you need something like a call trace (maybe neatly indented) or just plain method call logging with parameters and maybe return values, you will get quick results with AspectJ without cluttering your application code. The aspect can always be improved and maintained in a single spot, which is very clean. No need to be afraid of spaghetti aspect code. It will not happen if you don't totally abuse AspectJ.

You will only run into problems if your core code is already spaghetti code and you have very long methods which need log statements *inside* those methods and not around them. Then you might need to refactor and break down monster methods into smaller ones. But that is a problem no matter which logging approach you choose. My own experience with ugly legacy code and AspectJ-based logging tells me that it helps a lot because even spaghetti code calls other methods and that can be nicely traced in AspectJ.